# I wrote x86-64 Assembly. But it's not working under Windows, only on OnlineGDB (Linux)

Tags: assembly, gcc, compilation, x86-64, nasm

I wrote a x86-64 code in Assembly Language. The output is 17.

```
    .text
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
printint:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    nop
    leave
    ret

    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    $2, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    $5, %r10
    imulq   %r9, %r10
    addq    %r8, %r10
    movq    $8, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    %r8,%rax
    cqo
    idivq   %r9
    movq    %rax,%r8
    subq    %r10, %r8
    movq    %r10, %rdi
    call    printint
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

When i Compile this wth GCC, I got this errors.

```
out.s: Assembler messages:
out.s:5: Error: bad register name `%rbp'
out.s:6: Error: bad register name `%rsp'
out.s:7: Error: bad register name `%rsp'
out.s:8: Error: bad register name `%rbp)'
out.s:9: Error: bad register name `%rbp)'
out.s:11: Error: bad register name `%rip)'
out.s:19: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
out.s:19: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `m'
out.s:21: Error: bad register name `%rbp'
out.s:22: Error: bad register name `%rsp'
out.s:23: Error: bad register name `%r8'
out.s:24: Error: bad register name `%r9'
out.s:25: Error: bad register name `%r10'
out.s:26: Error: bad register name `%r9'
out.s:27: Error: bad register name `%r8'
out.s:28: Error: bad register name `%r8'
out.s:29: Error: bad register name `%r9'
out.s:30: Error: bad register name `%r8'
out.s:31: Error: `cqo' is only supported in 64-bit mode
out.s:32: Error: bad register name `%r9'
out.s:33: Error: bad register name `%rax'
out.s:34: Error: bad register name `%r10'
out.s:35: Error: bad register name `%r10'
out.s:38: Error: bad register name `%rbp'
```

Similarly when I did this in NASM, I got the following errors.

```
out.s:1: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
out.s:3: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:5: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:6: error: expression syntax error
out.s:7: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:8: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:9: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:10: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:11: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:12: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:18: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:19: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:21: error: label `pushq' inconsistently redefined
out.s:5: note: label `pushq' originally defined here
out.s:21: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:22: error: expression syntax error
out.s:23: error: expression syntax error
out.s:24: error: expression syntax error
out.s:25: error: expression syntax error
out.s:26: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:27: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:28: error: expression syntax error
out.s:29: error: expression syntax error
out.s:30: error: expression syntax error
out.s:32: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:33: error: expression syntax error
out.s:34: error: label `subq' inconsistently redefined
out.s:7: note: label `subq' originally defined here
out.s:34: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:35: error: expression syntax error
out.s:37: error: label `movl' inconsistently redefined
out.s:8: note: label `movl' originally defined here
out.s:37: error: parser: instruction expected
out.s:38: error: parser: instruction expected
```

But when i went to https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_gcc_assembler and compiled it, I got the correct answer (17).

[image: Screenshot]

I'm still learning assembly language. I searched for an answer, but could not found one. Can you explain the reason for this ?

Details about my Laptop

> AMD RYZEN 5 Processor ( x64 Based )
>
> 64bit Windows 10

Comment: You tagged this NASM, but that's GAS AT&T syntax.  NASM uses Intel syntax.  What commands did you use to try to assemble it?

Comment: And which GCC did you use locally? What do you get when you run `gcc -dumpmachine` ?

Comment: @Michael **mingw32** :|

Comment: @PeterCordes I only used **nasm out.s** ( out.s is a assembly file )

Comment: @LasanNishshanka: that's even worse; the default output format for NASM is a 16-bit flat binary.  But anyway, unless you rewrite it completely into Intel syntax with NASM directives, you can't use NASM to assemble it. Of course you'd have to rewrite most of the instructions anyway to port it to Windows.  Probably start again from C compiler output for Windows instead of for GNU/Linux.  (Your code is obviously slightly hand-tweaked GCC output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out.s:31: Error: 'cqo' is only supported in 64-bit mode` tells you that you tried to assemble this 64-bit code in 32-bit mode.  Perhaps you tried to use mingw32 under Windows, instead of 64-bit mingw?

This code is for x86-64 GNU/Linux: note the calling convention passing args in RDI, RSI, and use of `@plt`.  DLLs don't use a PLT, that's a GNU/Linux thing (traditional dynamic linking, not new style `gcc -fno-plt` with early instead of lazy binding).  That's why it works in OnlineGDB, which uses x86-64 GNU/Linux.

It won't work under 64-bit Windows, except inside WSL.  Even Cygwin 64 is a source compatiblity layer, not binary / ABI / calling convention.

---

Also, it's written in AT&T syntax with GAS directives.  NASM uses Intel syntax with different directives; no wonder nearly every single line is an error when you try to assemble it with `nasm -fwin64`.